# How to manage docker-compose.override.yml file between macOS and Windows?

Tags: windows, macos, docker, docker-compose

The situation is that I have three developers working on a project. One developer is on Mac OS X and the other two are on Windows 10 Pro machines. My project consists of .NET Core 3.1 SDK and utilizes docker support to run. It was created in Windows initially so the docker-compose.override.yml file has the following lines of code under Volumes:

```
- ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
- ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
```

This works perfectly on Windows environments. However on the Mac OS X side the developer constantly has to update the config of docker-compose.override.yml volumn links to look like the following:

```
- ~/.microsoft/usersecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
- ~/.aspnet/https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
```

Has anyone ever dealt with a situation like this? What did you do to overcome it besides asking the developer to BootCamp or Virtualize Windows 10 on their Mac?

Update:

I just tried to update the docker-compose.override.yml file to accept the Mac OS X volume lines. I ran it on my Windows machine as well as my Mac OS X machine. It seemed to work properly. I have reached out to my developers to test it out on their machines to see if it will work. Once I get their responses I will update this question.

Update #2:

Looks like my developers on both platforms are able to run the docker-compose project using the Mac OS X Volume lines.

Comment: Thank you for posting this. We had the exact scenario and this solution worked for our team as well. I know this was a while ago but do you know why it works? I can't for the life of me figure out where "~/.microsoft/usersecrets" maps to on my Windows machine.

Comment: @user3123744 I believe ~ is mapped to AppData folder for windows

Comment: @AlexSherzhukov ~ is mapped to user root folder. AppData is in it

Answer (score 0):

A few options come to mind:

- Have the Windows devs use WSL so the paths match Mac OS X
- Declare environment variables for each path and reference those in the config
- Have an extra compose file that contains the volume declarations but isn't checked into source control so it doesn't get overwritten

I've not done any of these so can't say if there's any pitfalls, but the 2nd and 3rd approaches I have used in the past on non-Docker projects where this kind of scenario occurs.

Comment: Thanks @chedabob could you provide a bit more detail on #2? That might be the easiest.

Comment: I am not sure if you can use env variables in that place.

Comment: @sroye98 The devs would export the variables through their preferred method (e.g. Through Control Panel -> System on Windows, and with `export` on Mac OS), then reference them just like `APPDATA` in your first snippet